# output only if within a combination of two cats

Tags: categories

What Im looking to do is look if on one page out put posts that have 2 cats selected (they must have both selected to be shown, not just one cat)

```
if (is_page(15) || $post->post_parent=="15") {
  $option1 = '11, 4';
  $option2 = '11, 7';}

  <?php $my_query_args = array( 
      'posts_per_page' => 10,
      'meta_key' => 'price',    
      'meta_value_num' => '',   
      'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num', 
      'order' => 'asc', 
      'tax_query' => array(
          array( 
            'taxonomy' => 'category',  
            'field' => 'id', 
            'terms' => array( $inventory_home ),
            'operator' => 'AND'
          ) 
      )
  );
$my_query = new WP_Query( $my_query_args );?>
```

Comment: Your code is rather unclear. What are $option1 and $option2? What is $inventory_home?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has some odd elements like `'meta_value_num' => '',` but it sounds to me like what you want is exactly [what `category__and` does](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters).

```
$my_query_args = array( 
     'posts_per_page' => 10,
     'meta_key' => 'price',    
     'category__and' => array($catid1,$catid2),   
     'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num', 
     'order' => 'asc'
);
```

Side note: your `price` meta key will not order in a way that you think is correct [unless the associated values actually are numbers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91160/list-upcoming-events-ordered-by-date-in-a-custom-field/91163#91163).

Comment: I will try that.. but does that require them to have BOTH categories in order to show?

Comment: Yes, `category__and` "shows posts that are in both categories".