# Checking 2 dates against todays date

Tags: custom-post-types

I am trying to display data from a custom post type, based on the date that the event will occur. The date is set in a meta box in the cpt.

My code so far is:

```
$today = date('d/m/Y');
$p_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_training_date', true);
$p_date2 = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_training_start_date', true);
if($p_date > $today) {
 // stuff
}
```

This works fine (only shows events after todays date) but I want to add in another event type (`$p_date2`) as well but if I do:

```
if($p_date > $today || $p_date2 > $today) {
 // stuff
}
```

It displays all the posts from the CPT

The date formats are all the same, so it's got to be with my if statement

any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you can compare date strings formatted that way. Try using YYYYMMDD as an integer or, my favorite, Unix timestamps.

Comment: Your date format is not going to sort correctly. I suspect that is the problem. It certainly _is_ a big problem. See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/78048/21376 Also: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/91163/21376

Comment: perfect guys, works as intended now :)

one small thing, is it possible to grab just the month from the date e.g. if mm = xx then display, as would like to try and display on a monthly list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For date manipulations you should use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class. Also, dates should be stored in `Y-m-d` format (if you're storing them differently you can create the DateTime object from a specified format: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php (php 5.3+) - but I recommend storing it in the unambiguous Y-m-d format ).

The following assumes `Y-m-d` formatin the post meta:

```
$today = new DateTime( 'now' );
$p_date = new DateTime( get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_training_date', true) );
$p_date2 = new DateTime( get_post_meta($post->ID, '_cmb_training_start_date', true) );

if( $p_date > $today || $p_date2 > $today) {
   // stuff
}
```

As you mention in [the comments](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102518/checking-2-dates-against-todays-date#comment141513_102518). You can also easily obtain year/monthy/day information:

```
if( $p_date2->format('m') == '01' ){
      //$p_date2 is in January
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as date comparisons go, I think a general good practise would be to convert your times to [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). Especically if there is a change of those dates being user-inputted, it's best to have them all at the same level.

I have a post [here](http://ericholmes.ca/date-comparisons-in-php/) that goes into it a little.