# Show future events based on custom field AND order by date

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I have a custom content type (event), within that type I have a custom date field, with the name: 'date'. In my template I am running the WP_Query to return a list of events. I would like to only get events that are in the future (according to my custom 'date' field) and then order the list by that same field.

I have tried the following but it simply returns a list of all the 'events' in the system, regardless of date

```
$today = date('d M, y');

$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'event',
    'meta_query'             => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'date',
            'value'     => $today,
            'compare'   => '>',
            'type'      => 'CHAR',
        ),
    ),
    'meta_key'               => 'date',
    'orderby'                => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'                  => 'ASC'
);
```

As a note: if I replace the type from 'CHAR' to 'DATE' I get no results returned...

Comment: How is your date stored in the database?

Comment: I am using a plugin to create the custom fields but I specified the same date format as the one listed for the $today variable...

Comment: I have just double checked and an example date in the database is: `14 Feb, 14`

Comment: your date format is meaningless to MySQL, you need to store it as numeric yyyy-mm-dd to be able to query and order on it correctly.

Comment: Ah ok, so do I need to do that at the point of data entry or can I convert it through php?

Comment: There are numerous possible duplicates, for example: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/91160/21376 Yes, you can convert via PHP but more detail would be needed to give you working code.

Comment: Hmmm ok, what extra details would you need to know to help?

Answer (score 3):

I found the actual issue so I thought I'd update.

ACF documentation says to use $today = date ('Ymd') to compare dates but you really need to use current_time('Ymd') so I removed the functions.php code that I added and fixed the problem rather than work around it.

Here's my query now

```
$event1 = current_time('Ymd');
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'events',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'event_date_ends',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'value' => $event1,
            )
            ),
    'meta_key' => 'event_date_ends',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ),
);
```

So for your query try this

```
$today = current_time('d M, y');

$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'event',
    'meta_query'             => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'date',
            'value'     => $today,
            'compare'   => '>=',
        ),
    ),
    'meta_key'               => 'date',
    'orderby'                => 'meta_value',
    'order'                  => 'ASC'
);
```

Just make sure the current_time ('d M, y') is how you have your data being stored via whatever date picker you're using or if you're typing it in each event in a field that's how you're typing it in. d M, y would read 19 Jun, 14. Remember your display date and stored date can read differently. I hope this helps.

Comment: This worked brilliantly for me. Much simpler too! Thanks.

Comment: Using `date('Ymd')` works for me. Maybe it has to do with which ACF version you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did. I am using the Advance Custom Fields plugin for the custom fields. I followed the instructions here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-advanced-custom-fields-sorting-by-date-picker, which states the easiest way to do this is to compare dates in unix timestamp format.

My date field in ACF is called: **event_start**
The date is being saved in my database in **yymmdd** format
I have the Custom Post Type: **events**

Step 1 is to create the Start Date Field in ACF.
Step 2 is to add this function to your functions.php (assuming PHP > 5.3) This function takes my human readable front-end input and converts to Unix timestamp and saves it in another post meta row.

```
function custom_unixtimesamp ( $post_id ) {
  if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'events' ) {
    $startdate = get_post_meta($post_id, 'event_start', true);
    if($startdate) {
        $newdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $startdate)->getTimestamp();
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'unixstartdate', $newdate  );
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'custom_unixtimesamp', 100, 2);
```

Step 3, now you can sort and compare on the Unix Timestamp

```
$today = time();            
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => '50',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'unixstartdate',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'value' => $today,
        )
    ),
    'meta_key'=>'event_start',  
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 1):

Marc's suggestion was pretty close.

Here's what worked for me and you can try too.

functions.php

```
function custom_unixtimesamp ( $post_id ) {
    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'events' ) {
    $startdate = get_post_meta($post_id, 'event_date_begins', true);

        if($startdate) {
            $dateparts = explode('/', $startdate);
            $newdate1 = strtotime(date('d.m.Y H:i:s', strtotime($dateparts[1].'/'.$dateparts[0].'/'.$dateparts[2])));
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'unixstartdate', $newdate1  );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'custom_unixtimesamp', 100, 2);
```

then query

```
$today = time();    

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'events',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'unixstartdate',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'value' => $today,
            )
            ),
    'meta_key' => 'event_date_begins',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about putting anything into your functions.php file, or saving timestamps, etc.  All you need to do is add the correct '**type**' value into your meta_query array, to let it know that you are comparing dates.  So the value of '**type**' sould be "**DATE**"...

Eg...

```
$today = current_time('Y-m-d');

$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'event',
    'meta_query'             => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'event_date',
            'value'     => $today,
            'compare'   => '>=',
            'type'      => 'DATE',
        ),
    ),
    'meta_key'               => 'event_date',
    'orderby'                => 'meta_value',
    'order'                  => 'ASC'
);
```

...In this example, my date-storing meta field is called 'event_date' and I am checking for entries with dates in the future (or today).