# WP_query parameters for date range

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, wp-query, query-posts

I'm using the [events manager plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/events-manager/) to create custom posts for events. I do not have a need for a blog, so I modified my theme's `index.php` file (using a child theme) for its query to retrieve the "event" post type on the home page.

`new WP_Query ( array( 'paged' => $paged, 'post_type' => 'event', 'posts_per_page' => 4  )` (I have only included the 'event' post type).

So far, so good. But it displays current, past and future events on the home page. I want it to only display current and future events (that is, **I want events that haven't started yet to be shown on the home page too. I only want to prevent past events from being shown**). I have taken a look at [the codex page for WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters) and used the following code excerpt:

```
// Create a new filtering function that will add our where clause to the query
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
    // posts for March 1 to March 15, 2010
    $where .= " AND post_date <  CURDATE() ";
    return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
$query = new WP_Query( $query_string );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' )
```

It doesn't produce the desired result because the event date isn't stored on `post_date` on the DB.

However I suppose there's some easy way to reference the events' dates, because the date automatically displayed on the home page isn't the posts publication date, *but rather the event start date, without any modification being made*.

Comment: presumably it's being stored in post meta, use `get_post_custom` to see all of the metadata associated with an event, and a [meta query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) to query based on the date key.

Comment: @Milo it is, but I don't know how to analyse it. Here's its output: http://pastebin.com/3er1WBMv

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Copied from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29279530/209859):

> `WP_Query` offers a `date_query` parameter, allowing you to set a range with before and after.
>
> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters

```php
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'     => 'January 1st, 2015',
            'before'    => 'December 31st, 2015',
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

See the linked documentation for more details.

Note that the other answer, which uses a postmeta query, is really out of date, no one should do that now that `WP_Query` supports these date queries.

Comment: Can you please add the WP version where this support has been added?

Comment: As it says on the Codex article I linked `date_query (array) - Date parameters (available since Version 3.7).` so it's truly ancient at this point, definitely safe to use :)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you need a `meta_query`.

```
$query = new WP_Query ( 
  array( 
    'paged' => $paged, 
    'post_type' => 'event', 
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key' => 'date_key_name',
        'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
        'compare' => '>=',
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Be aware that your dates need to be in some format that [a machine can parse correctly](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/75318/21376).

### Reference

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: the custom field is stored in the YYYY-MM-DD format. I've tried comparing using meta_key + meta_value, meta_query + key + value, '=' and 'LIKE' operators. Nothing seems to work. Even by inserting the literal event date.

Comment: Did you try the code I posted?

Comment: Well, no, because your code expects dates to be in unix time, I supposed (incorrectly?). I'll try it now.

Comment: `YYYY-MM-DD`, with or without the separators, will sort numerically. It is the only human date format that sorts numerically in the same way it sorts on a calendar. I tend to prefer `UNIXTIME`, or `DATE`/`DATETIME` column, but I believe that format should work.

Comment: What do I put as values of $date1 and $date2? I need to check if the event's end date has already passed, so I have to compare today's date and the event's end date, but how do I retrieve the event's end date to set it as one of the variables?

Comment: @ruda.almeida you want an `OR` relationship with the start and end keys- either the start date is equal to or greater than today's date, or the end date is equal to or greater than todays date.

Comment: @Milo no, I want events that haven't started yet to be shown on the home page too. I only want to prevent past events from being shown.

Comment: @ruda.almeida yes, that's what I said- either the start date is in the future, OR the end date is in the future.

Comment: @ruda.almeida : see the edit. Can't it raght now

Comment: @Milo if the end date is in the future, I suppose I can ignore the start date.

Comment: @ruda.almeida aha, that's true, hadn't thought of that! though if you want to order by start date, that key has to be part of the query.

Comment: @Milo aha, that's true, hadn't thought of that! ;-)

Comment: @s_ha_dum This edit is the code I had tryed myself when I read the codex on meta_query. Didn't work that time, I copied your code (changing "date_key_name" for "event_end_date, obviously, tha custom field's name). Didn't work. I think I'm doing something wrong =/

Comment: The field name in the DB is "`_event_end_date`", I had thought I needed to remove the first "_" but it works if I keep it.

Comment: That first underscore prevents the fields from showing up in the "Custom Meta" dropdown select box.