# Create custom post order (with custom post type meta)

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, loop, themes, order

I would like to display my custom post type by specific order.
In my custom post type, i've 2 meta :
- DAY ( Select : 1,2,3,4,5,etc...)
- MONTH ( Select : Janvier, Fevrier, Mars, Avril, etc...)

How it's possible to display this :

- DISPLAY CUSTOM POST TYPE BY DATE ( closest at first ).

Thanks.

Comment: You have only month and day fields? You don't store year value? Do you store these values as one or 2 separate custom fields?

Comment: I don't think there's really any point in storing the day and month separately, it's far simpler to query on a single field containing yyyy-mm-dd, and day and month can be easily extracted from this format for display.

Comment: How does _your_ day and month data differ from the day and month stored by WordPress? This seems like unnecessary complication.

Comment: Yes i've YEAR value, but if i know how do this with 2 values, i think it will be simple for 3 values :). Values are in 2 separate field.

Comment: @s_ha_dum because it's not post date, but the event date ;).

Comment: It is a different date. OK. That is fair.

Answer (score 0):

Save your data in a single field as either `YYYY-MM-DD` or [UNIXTIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Then query like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'POST_TYPE_NAME',
    'meta_key' => 'date-key-name',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

You should get an order, unless I am having a bad morning, of Day -> Month -> Year, which I believe is what you want. I don't have your data at hand so I can't actually test that.

## Related

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/75318/21376