# Help sorting by Meta Key value

Tags: custom-field, search

using this https://github.com/growthspark/wp-advanced-search I am not sure how to sort by meta_key value. I currently have a meta key called "Due Date" with the date entered like 06/06/2012 (M/D/Y). The search framework is nothing special, as it is simply php and wordpress codex standards so I hope someone can help.

I have something like this

```
               $args['fields'][] = array('type' => 'meta_key',
                                        label' => 'Test',
                                        'meta_key' => '',
                                        'format' => 'select',
                                        'values' => array());
```

but it is not right. Any ideas?

Comment: The date you have should either be stored as mysql date format OR convert it to unix timestamp.  Or else it won't know how to sort that.

Comment: See: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/75318/21376

Comment: See also: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/78048/21376

Comment: Cool, Thanks guys. I was obviously NOT looking for the answer as you dont learn anything that way. Reading up on these things now :)